# How to squash a Python project into a single file

Tags: python

I have the following file structure

```
/src
  /test
    extra.py
  main.py
```

extra.py

```
def hello:
  print("hello")
```

main.py

```
from test import extra
extra.hello()
```

is it possible to produce a single file

```
def hello:
  print("hello")

hello()
```

Comment: seems like [XY-Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @ Ahmed I. Elsayed Thanks, interesting reading. How should I modify my question?

Comment: what is your end goal? Why not just use one file here? What's the real issue

Comment: I got your point. However, having one file is too big to maintain. I want to break it into some logical parts. But then squash the whole project into one file to deploy to the target environment

Comment: Do you mean an executable?

Comment: not entirely, the end result should be also a python file

Comment: Look into [creating a python package](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/). That is typically how Python projects are installed/deployed.

Comment: Simply flattening multiple files into one introduces problems even if you do so manually. You may have identical names defined in multiple modules that would need to be renamed if you created a single flat module. Packaging is the solution to your problem, not creating a single `.py` file.

Comment: jakub, chepner, thanks. I'm still looking for a way to flatten the project. Since the target environment only accept one python file. The uniqueness could be addressed since everything is located within the scope of the project

Comment: Can the single file to bootstrap the project into a temporary working folder during execution? eg. `unzip project.zip /tmp/project/... && python /tmp/project/code.py`